# parcel html настройка проекта

Tags: javascript, html, сборка

Коллеги такой вопрос. Использую сборщик parcel.Вопрос? 
Хочу избавится от дублирования верстки на станицах, разбить ее на модули и инклюдить в требуемых местах. Вроде как это реализуется с помощью posthtml-include, то толковой инфы не нашел. В англ. не понимаю, прошу русский источник.

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install posthtml-include --save-dev
```

Создаем файл `.posthtmlrc.js`
в него пишем

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    'posthtml-include': {
      root: __dirname + '/site',
    }
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>index.html</title>
</head>
<body>
    <include src="components/button.html"></include>
</body>
</html>
```

components/button.html

```
<button class="button"><div class="button__text">Button</div></button>
```